# Questions about default class functions in Python

Tags: python, class, methods

Consider the following example of an iterative class which makes factorials from a given number:

```
import math

class Factorial(object):
  def __init__(self, num, maxsize=10e12):
    self.num = num
    self.maxsize = maxsize
  def __repr__(self):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
      return f'<{self.__class__.__name__} object at {hex(id(self.__class__))}>'
    else:
      return '<' + self.__class__.__module__ + '.' + self.__class__.__name__ + ' object at ' + hex(id(self.__class__)) + '>'
  def __iter__(self):
    for i in range(1,self.num+1):
      if math.factorial(i) > self.maxsize:
        break
      yield math.factorial(i)
```

So, of course we have the methods `__init__`, `__repr__`, and `__iter__`, which I have all read about online. I have two questions:

1. What would you call these methods? I know you can describe `__init__` as a sort of constructor, but is there a special name that all of those `__<blah>__` methods fall under when it comes to classes?
2. Is there a list of all of these so-called "special" or "built-in" class functions that tells what they are and what they do in a class context? The ones I already know of are `__init__`, `__enter__`, `__next__`, `__exit__`, `__iter__`, `__str__`, `__repr__`, and `__call__`. Or is this pretty much a complete list, except for a few?

I've been scratching my head about this for a while now (mostly because I don't know what to call these functions so I can't really research them).

Comment: I don't think there is an "official" name, but most people call them magic methods (which I personally don't like), special methods, or datamodel methods.  I like that one, because searching for that term will bring up the [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) page of the documentation, which describes most of those methods.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Would it be under the "Special method names" list? That's what it appears to be.

Comment: The docs call them [special methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names). As Patrick says, they're often called magic methods. Another name is [dunder](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200605/dunder.html) methods

Comment: Thank you! Is there possibly a simpler guide to the special methods?

Comment: I've heard of them referred to as magic methods. https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/

Comment: That guide by Rafe Kettler is very good. Here's his [Github page](https://github.com/RafeKettler/magicmethods) for that document in various formats.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh If you post, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's no answer to this reasonable question, I'll summarize the suggestions given in the comments as a community wiki.

The official Python documentation mostly calls methods like `__init__` and `__iter__` "special methods." It has a list of them [in its chapter on the Python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names).

Python programmers often uses the less formal term "magic methods". Or, since the names are surrounded by double-underscores, the term "dunder method" may make sense, especially when you're going to need to be speaking their names out loud (you can say "dunder init" as a simple and clear way to express the name `__init__` without tying your tongue in knots, an approach [popularized by Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200605/dunder.html)).

It's worth noting that some objects have special attributes that are not actually methods. For example, functions and modules have a `__name__` attribute that is a string. (The module's `__name__` is usable as a global variable within the module, and you'll often see used that way in `if __name__ == "__main__"` boilerplate.) All objects should have a `__class__` attribute (which is a reference to their type), and many will have a `__dict__` attribute (a dictionary) as well.